Microsoft ASPNet Identity Owin PasswordSignInAsync not working when accessing site with IP Address of IIS Server
I am having an issue when trying to login to our MVC ASP.Net Application. It works if I pull up a browser on the server and utilize localhost. When I use the IP Address of that server, it continues to redirect me to the login screen.
I did find that the sign in is coming back as "Success". I tested this by turning off Authorization on the Home controllers Index action, and It went to the Index screen after logging in.
  //[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DashboardConfigurator.Default.SetConnectionStringsProvider(new ConfigFileConnectionStringsProvider());
        DashboardConfigurator.Default.AllowExecutingCustomSql = true;

        return View();
    }

When the Authorize is commented back in, it will continue to redirect me to the login screen.
I did notice, when logging in via Localhost, instead of using the IP Address, I was getting the User's Username in the Login Partial View that I have. But when I turned off the [Authorize] and had a successful login, it did not return the User's User Name in the Login Partial view.
So I am thinking maybe it has something to do with a cookie issue. This website, does not have a domain name yet, only an IP Address for now, so I don't know if maybe that is the issue, and I need to set a fake domain name out there for the cookie to attach to or not?
Below is my code located in the Startup class.
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and role manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        
        bool isLocal = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal;

        if (!isLocal)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                CookieName = "Gen",
                
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
                SlidingExpiration = true,



            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                
                
                CookieName = "Gen",
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
                SlidingExpiration = true,

            });
        }
       }

Below will show my Login Partial view which is pretty standard, but the only way that the User Name would not show is if the Request.IsAuthenticated returned false, so I'm thinking the cookie is not being created correctly for an IP Address, or it has something to do with security that needs set on the IIS Server, but I am stumped on this one!
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
        <span class="loginLink">@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "! ", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: new { area = "" }, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })</span>
        <span> | </span>
        <span class="loginLink"><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></span>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right:2em;">
        <!-- <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li> -->
        @Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
    </ul>
}

Any Help is greatly appreciated!

In production people only use valid domain names to access web apps, never with IP addresses, so no system is specifically designed to work with that. (There are often special arrangements for localhost, however.)

Hi I appreciate the comment, but I have created web apps where users could access it via IP Addresses (with login) so they could see the development before completion, and then the client would obtain a domain name which would be set up near the end of development.

@Eric Is there a specific reason you are providing the CookieName and CookieSecure during your cookie creation?? Have you tried using the default settings?

Let me try to revert back to default settings!

Yes it was due to the Cookie Name! Thank you!

@Eric I think you should post an answer to this as to what you did to resolve it.

Will do I want to find the reason first on why that was causing it and then I will post the answer with what I found
